# Why am i getting a SIGABRT error in this code

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sigabrt

I have writen this code in CodeChef but it constantly gives me runtime error called (SIGABRT). I have been trying to resolve this issue yet there is no result. I have reduced memory to my fullest. I need help.

There are N students standing in a row and numbered 1 through N from left to right. You are given a string S with length N, where for each valid i, the i-th character of S is 'x' if the i-th student is a girl or 'y' if this student is a boy. Students standing next to each other in the row are friends.

The students are asked to form pairs for a dance competition. Each pair must consist of a boy and a girl. Two students can only form a pair if they are friends. Each student can only be part of at most one pair. What is the maximum number of pairs that can be formed?

Example Input
3
xy
xyxxy
yy

Example Output
1
2
0

Explanation
Example case 1: There is only one possible pair: (first student, second student).

Example case 2: One of the ways to form two pairs is: (first student, second student) and (fourth student, fifth student).

Another way to form two pairs is: (second student, third student) and (fourth student, fifth student).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define rp(l,p) for(int l = 0; l < p; l+=2)
#define s string 
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    // your code goes here
    int t = 0;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        s n = "";
        ll max = 0;
        cin >> n;
        if(n.size()%2 == 0){
            rp(l, n.size()-1){
                if(n.substr(0+l, 2) == "xy" || n.substr(0+l, 2) == "yx"){
                    max+=1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(n.size()%2 == 1){
            s x = n.substr(n.size()-1, 1);
            n.resize(n.size()-1);
            for(int m = 0; m <= (n.size()-1); m+=2){
                if(n.substr(0+m, 2) == "xy" || n.substr(0+m, 2) == "yx"){
                    max+=1;
                }
            }
            n.append(x);
            if(n.substr(n.size()-3,2) == "xy" || n.substr(n.size()-3,2) == "yx"){

            }
            else if(n.substr(n.size()-2,2) == "xy" || n.substr(n.size()-2,2)=="yx"){
                max+=1;
            }
        }
        cout << max << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some sample input that causes the issue would help

Comment: Because of all these macros, and non-descriptive one-character variables, the shown code is hard to understand. If I were to ask others for help in figuring out a problem with my code, I would try to make it as easy to understand and as descriptive as possible. The easier I make my code understandable, for others, the more likely it will be that someone can see the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error without knowing the input. Here is the [link](https://cee.studio/?bucket=200608-45d&name=JtPDP),  you can use your input to trigger the sigabrt and debug it.   Just click "Start" to build your code, and run it in the Terminal.

Comment: I ran your code with the suggested input and it worked. Can you provide some input that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully aggree with @Sam Varshavchik

However, I tried you're code with following input:

1. try

   $ ./test

   input 2

   input ha

   output 0

   input lo

   output 0
   => no crash
2. try

   $ ./test

   input 2

   input ha

   output 0

   input lo

   output 0

=> no crash

3. try

   $ ./test

   input 2

   **input a**

   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
     what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 2) > this->size() (which is 0)
   Aborted (core dumped)

So let's analyze you're code. It seems to crash when string n has size of 1.

In you're substr calls there are lot of hardcoded integers without any validation if string has the required length (aka substr(...,2))